# Interacting with a Server Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a page that is supposed to incorporate AJAX to interact with a server and am having some trouble figuring out what to do.

Here is what's supposed to happen:

1. Create a form that validates according to a set of rules (I've done this and have it working properly so won't bore you with the details, although they should be clearly visible in my code which I will include).
2. If the form passes validation successfully, follow the server validation handshake instructions.

Here are the automated validation handshake instructions:

1. If the form has been validated successfully, log into the server with the password from the form and with the "login" parameter.
       NOTE: The only password accepted by the server is 1234
2. You will then get back a time-based key that is only valid for a short time. It will be in the form of "valid:" + a series of numbers and colons.
3. After you get the key, strip off the "valid:" and send only the state information to the server with the key with the "verify" parameter. Specifically, send it in this manner: stateValue + strippedKey
       For example, if the user chose "LA" and the returned was "valid:46:10:10:33:46" then send to the server "LA46:10:10:33:46".
4. The server will then send back a series of numbers and letters
5. Using those numbers and letters that were sent back, send them back with the "submit" parameter, the state, and the person's name with a colon between each.
       The form will tell you whether you were successful or not.

I have never worked with AJAX before so have been trying to work along with a tutorial on the W3school website, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply it to these instructions.

Here is what I have so far: (most of the AJAX code (function ajax()) was modeled after part of the code our instructor wrote in class, however he commented out the "login = 1234" part so I'm unsure of the syntax that was there before he did this)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project 5</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            First Name: <input type="text" id="name"> <br>
            <span id="nameErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            Age: <input type="text" id="age"> <br>
            <span id="ageErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            Street Address: <input type="text" id="address"> <br>
            <span id="addressErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            State: <select>
                <option value="la">LA</option>
                <option value="tx">TX</option>
                <option value="ok">OK</option>
                <option value="mi">MI</option>
                <option value="az">AZ</option>
            </select> <br>
            Login Password: <input type="password" id="password"> <br>
            <span id="passwordErrMsg" class="error"></span> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm() {
                var ckName = checkName();
                var ckAge = checkAge();
                var ckAddress = checkAddress();
                var ckPassword = checkPassword();

                return ckName && ckAge && ckAddress && ckPassword;
            }

            function checkName() {
                var form = document.myForm;
                var fName = form.name.value;
                var errMsgHolder = document.getElementById("nameErrMsg");
                if(fName.length < 3) {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = "Please enter a name with at least three letters";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(!(/^\S{3,}$/.test(fName))) {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = "Name cannot contain spaces";
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    errMsgHolder.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined; 
                }
            }

            function checkAge() {
                var form = document.myForm;
                var personAge = form.age.value;
                var ageErr = document.getElementById("ageErrMsg");
                if(personAge === "") {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your age";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(/\D/.test(personAge)) {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = "Please enter a numeric age";
                    return false
                }
                else {
                    ageErr.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined;
                }
            }

            function checkAddress() {
                var form = document.myForm;
                var strAddress = form.address.value;
                var addressErr = document.getElementById("addressErrMsg");
                if(strAddress === "") {
                    addressErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your address";
                    return false;
                }
                else if(strAddress.length < 12) {
                    addressErr.innerHTML = "Address must contain at least 12 characters";
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    addressErr.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined;
                }
            }

            function checkPassword() {
                var form = document.myForm;
                var passwd = form.password.value;
                var passwordErr = document.getElementById("passwordErrMsg");
                if(passwd === "") {
                    passwordErr.innerHTML = "Please enter your password"
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    passwordErr.innerHTML = " ";
                    return undefined;
                }
            }

            function ajax() {
                var url = "http://cs.sfasu.edu/rball/351/project5.php";
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var concat = url+"?"+passwd;
                alert("sending:"+concat);
                request.open("GET",concat, login=1234");
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Would anyone be willing to help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Make life simpler ~ http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: *"trying to work along with a tutorial on the W3school website"* ~ this site is generally frowned upon by the web-dev community. I suggest you find some better resources.

Comment: @Phil Sounds like it's part of a class assignment which explains the convoluted authentication handshake mechanism.

Comment: @JeremyMiller that doesn't rule out using tools / utilities / libraries to make the process easier. It's what we do in the real world

Comment: I'd suggest you either get a library that makes Ajax a lot, lot simpler (such as jQuery) or you start studying here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.  You will also need to study and learn how an asynchronous response can be processed.  A search for "plain javascript ajax code" will find you plenty of examples for how to make ajax calls.

Comment: @Phil So very true.  If only all instructors lived in the real world, lol.

Comment: Urgh, the *service* is responding with plain text yet the content-type says "text/html". It also responds with a 200 status for error conditions (response text says "invalid"). What on Earth are they actually trying to teach here?

Comment: I wish we could use jQuery, but we were specifically told not to until we cover it later this semester (I don't know much about it, but it sounds like it makes things much simpler). As for w3schools, it was the first thing that popped up on Google so I went with it ha. Since I know the bare bones minimum about programming it's usually pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code and looks like you were trying to pass the password in place of TRUE/FALSE value as third parameter. If you want to use login=1234 hardbind in the code, you can use the function below.

```html
 function ajax() {
                var url = "http://cs.sfasu.edu/rball/351/project5.php";
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var concat = url+"?login=1234";
                alert("sending:"+concat);
                request.open("GET",concat);
}
```

else, if you want to pass the password field value dynamically, you can just replace the 1234 with passwd variable. Like shown below.

```html
 function ajax() {
                var url = "http://cs.sfasu.edu/rball/351/project5.php";
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var passwd = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var concat = url+"?login="+passwd;
                alert("sending:"+concat);
                request.open("GET",concat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion worked. Now just to figure out what to do from here.Thanks again :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you have any questions. I'll be happy to answer.